# issue with delete button javascript

Tags: javascript

Heyy, I am new to javascript, and i am trying to understand how delete and update buttons work. i saw many suggestions but my delete button doesnt seem to work, I dont know where i went wrong. Help please

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function Delete(object){
            table = document.getElementById("table");
            row = document.getElementById(object);

            table.removeChild(row);
        };
    </script>

    <table id="table" class="table .table-bordered" style="width:50%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>DOB</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Martial Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Sara</td>
                        <td>1-12-1990</td>
                        <td>Female</td>
                        <td>Married</td>
                        <button>Edit</button>
                        <button onclick="Delete">Delete</button>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
```

and one more problem is that the delete button is showing on top of the table not in the action column why?

Comment: To answer the second question You must wrap your buttons in `<td>` elements like the others

Comment: you must give `onclick` a function like that `onclick="Delete(id)"`

Comment: yeah i forgot the parameters, but in my case which id it should be? i need to delete all the row @IslamZedan

Comment: the id should be the `<tr>` id to remove it

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the element as an argument to `Delete()`. The element is not an ID, so you shouldn't use `getElementById` with it, just access the element directly. You can use `parentElement` to go up the DOM hierarchy to find the containing row and table.

To solve the layout problem, you need to put the buttons inside `<td>`. Everything in a table row has to be in either `<td>` or `<th>`.

```js
function Delete(object) {
  var row = object.parentElement.parentElement;
  var table = row.parentElement;
  table.removeChild(row);
};
```

```html
<table id="table" class="table .table-bordered" style="width:50%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Martial Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>1-12-1990</td>
      <td>Female</td>
      <td>Married</td>
      <td><button>Edit</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="Delete(this)">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The buttons should also go into a table cell

```
<td>
<button>Edit</button>
<button onclick="Delete();">Delete</button>
</td>
```

You also have to change the click event to be as above:

```
<button onclick="Delete();">Delete</button>
```

Comment: This wont work. No actual parameters are supplied to `Delete()`.